# Date Arithmetic in PHP

Tags: php

Is there a PHP function I can use to do something like the following:

- Get the date 6 months ago (e.g. now - 6 months)?
- Get the date 2 years from now (e.g. now + 2 years)?

Comment: I thought PHP's `strtotime()` was fairly ubiquitous.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Yes, there is: [strtotime()](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php):

1. 6 months ago: `strtotime("-6 months");`
2. 2 years: `strtotime("+2 years");`

These will return Unix timestamps. So you might want to put the result into `date()` or `localtime()` or `gmtime()`.

Please do not try to subtract 6 months or add 2 years of seconds to `time()`. This does not take into account things like daylight saving or leap seconds and still gives you a value in seconds which is unlikely to be the precision you need. Let the library functions do it.

Comment: Thanks. `strtotime` is exactly what I needed.

Comment: The date arithmetic is a bit questionable. For example `date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-1 month', strtotime('2013-03-31')))` gives `2013-03-03`.

Comment: @Tammlyn That is an interesting bug! I'm fairly sure that strtotime calls the underlying glibc call.

Comment: Oh - I know why it did that: It made Mar 31 to Feb 31 which doesn't exist, so then it converted that to Mar 3. That's a tricky error to solve!

Answer (score 12):

Like this:

```
$date6monthsago = strtotime('-6 months');
$date2year = strtotime('+2 year');
```

Answer (score 6):

Choose according to your use following code..

```
echo date('m/d/Y',strtotime("-6 months")); //ago 6month o/p 05/23/2011 
echo date('d-m-Y',strtotime("6 months"));  //comming 6month o/p 23-05-2012
echo date('m.d.Y',strtotime("+2 years"));  //comming year o/p 11.23.2013
```

Answer (score 0):

https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.add.php and similar "new" methods may also be your friend.