# PHP - Sum time to current time, best practice

Tags: php, datetime, time, sum

Hi i'm trying to sum time with the current date time, this code seems to work:

```
$now = time();
$_day = strtotime('+1day',$now);
$_week = strtotime('+7day',$now);
$_month = strtotime('+1month',$now);
$_year = strtotime('+1year',$now);
```

what i'm wondering is if is there any other way , maybe better way of doing this .. can anyone show me new ways and the reasons why i should turn to another syntax?
I would like to do this more accurate as possible, so if i can reflect this script it is great!

thanks

EDIT:

just to be clear i need to use unix timestamps i don't need formatted dates/datetimes

Comment: Well, there are `DateTime::add` and `DateInterval` >= PHP 5.3.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If PHP version you use allows (PHP 5 >= 5.3.0) you to use [DateTime](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) and [DateInterval](http://php.net/manual/en/class.dateinterval.php) classes, you coud use them.

example:

```
$dateTime=new DateTime();
$plusDay=new DateInterval('P1D');
var_dump($dateTime->add($plusDay));

$dateTime=new DateTime();
$plusWeek=new DateInterval('P1W');
var_dump($dateTime->add($plusWeek));

$dateTime=new DateTime();
$plusMonth=new DateInterval('P1M');
var_dump($dateTime->add($plusMonth));
```

I hope this is helpful.

Comment: If you are running `(PHP 5 >= 5.3.0)`

Comment: yes, correct. I didn't mentioned this explicitly in the post.. But `if php version allows..` hints that datetime and dateinterval classes aren't available in old php-versions :)

Comment: It wasn't meant as an insult. Tried the code out of curiosity and realised in the process that my Xampp version needs updating. Cheers :)

Comment: Do not worry. I was not injured :) 
Cheers

Comment: @RuslanPolutsygan sorry to be sure, what's the sintax for +1year?

Comment: @Badaboooooom 1 year interval - `$plusYear=new DateInterval('P1Y');`
check syntax of string passed into constructor http://php.net/manual/en/dateinterval.construct.php

Answer (score 1):

I believe that [`strtotime()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) is as simple as you're going to get in PHP. All 3 of the answers to [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8235896/date-arithmetic-in-php) chose to use that syntax, and all of the various tutorials I see around the web use it. `strtotime()` makes thinking about date arithmetic a lot easier than other approaches.

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution:

```
date("Y-m-d", strtotime("+1 day"));
date("Y-m-d", strtotime("+7 days"));
date("Y-m-d", strtotime("+1 month"));
date("Y-m-d", strtotime("+1 year"));
```

Comment: that seems returning formatted dates , not tested but i'm looking for unix timestamps

Comment: @imRcH sorry for the down vote. it happened accidentally. Could you make some changes on your answer then I can avoid this unwanted down vote.