# PHP convert the day date with the time

Tags: php, date, time, timestamp

I am working on my php script to set up the date with the time. I need some help with convert the day date to the current day and next day date, example: my current time is `15:27` and my current date is `27-11-2019` so when I have the string for the variable `get_time1` is `06:00:00`, I want to convert it to `28-11-2019 06:00:00`. When I have the variable `get_time2` that have the time which it is `23:00:00` as my current time is before `23:00:00` so i want to convert the date with the current date with the time to `27-11-2019 23:00:00`.

Code:

```
<?php

$get_time1 = '06:00:00';
$get_time2 = '23:00:00';

date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London');

$Date = date('Y-m-d');
$time = date('H:i:s');

?>
```

Can you please show me an example how I can set up the day date with the time `06:00:00` and `23:00:00` as if the time `06:00:00` is after 12am to set up the next day date and if the time `23:00:00` is before 12am then set up the time with the current date?

Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP date(); with timezone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20288789/php-date-with-timezone)

Comment: This has got to be duplicated at least 100 times.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Date Arithmetic in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8235896/date-arithmetic-in-php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This just creates a DateTime object from the time (which will default it to todays date) and if this is less than the current date and time, it adds 1 day...

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat("H:i:s", $get_time2);

if ( $date < new DateTime() )   {
    $date->modify("+1 day");
}
```

which gives

```
2019-11-27 23:00:00
```

and for `$get_time1`...

```
2019-11-28 06:00:00
```

Comment: thank you very much for this, in your code that you wrote if I have the time `06:00:00`, how i can add it to the next day and when I have the time `23:00:00` how I can use the current day date with the time? I want to use 2 different times as i can set up the date to send the emails when the time is passed.

Comment: Sorry - I've changed the code - this checks that the time is in the future now (using `<`)

Answer (score 0):

If you use a [`DateTime`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.construct.php) that will allow you to do [date arithmetic](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.examples-arithmetic.php).

```
$now = new DateTime();
$tomorrow = $now->modify("+1 day");
```

You can also use `strtotime` to get a unix timestamp as explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8235918/2763026).

```
$tomorrow = strtotime('+1 day');
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe this will do?

```
$offset = timezone_offset_get( timezone_open( "Europe/London" ), new \DateTime() );
echo 'in London' . gmdate('d-m-Y H:i:s', date( "U" )+$offset);

echo 'current location: ' . date('d-m-Y H:i:s', date( "U" ));
```